# How to count the difference between two values in SQL?

Tags: sql

Sorry if my title is not detailed

I have two tables

**Game** table:

```
homeTeam int
awayTeam int 
homePoints int
awayPoints int
```

**Team**

```
tid  int
name varchar(20)
```

I am trying to find the number of games won at home by a specific team, lets say 'cops', with Team.tid = Game.homeTeam and wins are counted if homePoints > awayPoints

I want to end up with

```
Team    HomeWins
-----------------
Cops       20
```

How do I go about that?

## EDIT: #

I Managed to get my answer using

```
SELECT t.name, count(CASE WHEN homePoints > awayPoints then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Home Wins"
from Team t 
JOIN Game g 
ON t.tid = g.homeTeam
where t.name = 'Patriots'
GROUP BY t.name
```

some of the other answers were giving me the following errors

```
Column 'team.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: With `COUNT`, a `JOIN` between the two tables  and a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `join` the tables to be able to get both `name` and `homePoints` and use `COUNT` by `homePoints` and `group by` using `team id` to see a result for each team.

```
SELECT 
    T.name, COUNT(G.homePoints)
FROM
    team T
        INNER JOIN
    game G ON G.homeTeam = T.tid
WHERE
    G.homePoints > G.awayPoints
GROUP BY T.tid, T.name;
```

**OR** if you need the result for a specific team by providing it's id, you may drop the `GROUP BY` and add condition in the `WHERE`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    T.name, COUNT(T.tid)
FROM
    team T
        INNER JOIN
    game G ON G.homeTeam = T.tid
WHERE
    G.homePoints > G.awayPoints and T.tid = :request_team_id;
```

Comment: This query will give the no. of home wins by all teams

Answer (score 0):

First `SELECT` the columns that we want to display and use `AS` to specify they headings.

```
SELECT
    team.name as 'Team',
    COUNT(game.homePoints) AS 'HomeWins'
FROM dbo.team
```

Then we use `INNER JOIN` to only include the entries in `game` table, which match the Team ID in the `homeTeam` column vs what we selected from the `team` table.

```
INNER JOIN game on team.tid = game.homeTeam
```

Then we add a `WHERE` clause to limit it to only the team we ask for `team.name = 'cops'` and only include wins by that team

```
WHERE
    team.name = 'cops'
    AND game.homePoints > game.awayPoints
```

***So all together your script should look like this;***

```
SELECT
    team.name as 'Team',
    COUNT(game.homePoints) AS 'HomeWins'
FROM dbo.team

INNER JOIN game on team.tid = game.homeTeam

WHERE
    team.name = 'cops'
    AND game.homePoints > game.awayPoints
GROUP BY team.name
```